# Scala object constructor

Tags: scala

I have to create a file loader object and I would like the file to be loaded only once at object creation.
What I did until now is create a trait with a method read that will read file and output a list of String.

```
trait Loader {
  protected val readSource: List[String] = {
    Source
      .fromInputStream(getClass.getResourceAsStream("filename"), "UTF-8")
      .getLines()
      .toList
  }

  def transform(delimeter: String): Vector[C] = {
    val lines = readSource
    // process the lines
  }
}
```

The trait is implemented by several object, and the transform method can be called multiple times in the client code.

I would like to avoid re reading the file each time the transform method is called and my first solution was to extract the `val lines = readSource` from the transform method and make a function of it `def loadFile = readSource` and to create a apply method in my objects to call loadFile like so :

```
object MyLoader extends Loader {
  def apply: List[String] = {
    loadFile
  }
}
```

I am wondering if this is the right way to do it.  Thank you for your advices.

Comment: Despite the name, `readSource` is not a method, it is just a `val` that is initialised once when the object is created, so the file is not read each time you call `transform`. However I would make this a `lazy val` so that it is not initialised until it is first used, which will be after the object is initialised.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the resource read once for all, then you should do that in a singleton object, which will be initialized once lazily.

Clients should use that object. "Prefer composition over inheritance" is the mantra.

If you want a mix-in that makes it easy to use the object, you can use "self-types" to constrain clients:

```
trait HasResource { val resource: R = TheResource }
trait Client { self: HasResource => def getR: R = resource }
```

This is the "cake pattern" way of making stuff available.